# MySQL - Selecting multiple columns from multiple tables

Tags: mysql

I have three tables. Two of them are separate irrelevant tables (students and subjects), the third (entries) is one which links them both with foreign keys (student_id and subject_id).

Here are all the tables with the records:

students:

```
+------------+------------+-----------+---------------------+----------------------+
| student_id | first_name | surname   | email               | reg_date             |
+------------+------------+-----------+---------------------+----------------------+
|          1 | Emma       | Harvey    | emmah@gmail.com     | 2012-10-14  11:14:13|
|          2 | Daniel     | ALexander | daniela@hotmail.com | 2014-08-19  08:08:23 |
|          3 | Sarah      | Bell      | sbell@gmail.com     | 1998-07-04  13:16:32 |
+------------+------------+-----------+---------------------+----------------------+
```

subjects:

```
+------------+--------------+------------+----------------+
| subject_id | subject_name | exam_board | level_of_entry |
+------------+--------------+------------+----------------+
|          1 | Art          | CCEA       | AS             |
|          2 | Biology      | CCEA       | A              |
|          3 | Computing    | OCR        | GCSE           |
|          4 | French       | CCEA       | GCSE           |
|          5 | Maths        | OCR        | AS             |
|          6 | Chemistry    | CCEA       | GCSE           |
|          7 | Physics      | OCR        | AS             |
|          8 | RS           | CCEA       | GCSE           |
+------------+--------------+------------+----------------+
```

entries:

```
+----------+---------------+---------------+------------+
| entry_id | student_id_fk | subject_id_fk | entry_date |
+----------+---------------+---------------+------------+
|        1 |             1 |             1 | 2012-10-15 |
|        2 |             1 |             4 | 2011-09-21 |
|        3 |             1 |             3 | 2015-08-10 |
|        4 |             2 |             6 | 1992-07-13 |
|        5 |             3 |             7 | 2013-02-12 |
|        6 |             3 |             8 | 2016-01-14 |
+----------+---------------+---------------+------------+
```

How would I go about selecting, say, the emails of each student (*students* table) and the subject_name (*subjects* table), of those with the exam board OCR (using the entries table)? So basically selecting multiple columns from multiple tables, using a sort of overhead table. The desired output is something like this:

```
email           | subject_name
------------------------------
emmah@gmail.com | Computing
sbell@gmail.com | Physics
```

(Sorry, I don't know how to recreate the table properly in the question box).

I figure it starts with

```
SELECT student.email, subjects.subject_name
FROM students, subjects
```

But after that I've not really much of an idea, apart from that it uses joins.

Help is HUGELY appreciated!! So thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right track. What you need to do is to use the `entries` table to connect the other two tables using the primary and foreign keys, like this:

```
SELECT student.email, subjects.subject_name
FROM students
INNER JOIN entries  ON students.student_id = entries.student_id_fk 
INNER JOIN subjects ON subjects.subject_id = entries.subject_id_fk 
WHERE subjects.exam_board = 'OCR'
```

Comment: Thank you! Although can I ask, is the join used shorthand for an inner join, or something else?

Comment: @Dovahkiin It's shorthand for an `INNER JOIN` yes. I'll edit the answer to make it explicit instead.

Comment: have in mind that is better to use the ´join´ or ´inner join´ instead of a comma